# Export table object to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, ms-word

We extracted the required tables from word doc, but can someone help... that how can I export this table object `$LETable` to CSV, or export values which we have fetched below in CSV in table format.

```
$objWord = New-Object -Com Word.Application
$filename = 'D:\Files\Scan1.doc'
$objDocument = $objWord.Documents.Open($filename)

$LETable = $objDocument.Tables.Item(4)
$LETableCols = $LETable.Columns.Count
$LETableRows = $LETable.Rows.Count

$obj = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject

Write-Output "Starting to write... "

for($r=1; $r -le $LETableRows; $r++) {
    for($c=1; $c -le $LETableCols; $c++) {
        #Write-Host $r "x" $c
        $content = $LETable.Cell($r,$c).Range.Text
        Write-Host $content
    }
}
$objDocument.Close()
$objWord.Quit()
# Stop Winword Process
$rc = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objWord)
```

Comment: The pattern would be like this: 1) Create an ArrayList to hold objects. 2) Iterate thrugh each row in the table and create an object that has a property for each colum in the table. 3) Populate the properties by iterating all the cells in that row. 4) Add that object to the ArrayList. 5) Continue until all the rows are iterated. 6) Export the ArrayList to CSV.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I've removed the VBA tag; this is a PowerShell question, all the VBA experts in the world won't be able to help here, lest they also happen to know PowerShell.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I added the tag specifically b/c this is as much a (Word-)VBA question as it is a PowerShell question.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers the [tag:ms-word] tag carries that information. VBA is a language, not a type library. Here the language is PowerShell....

Comment: Does the frst row of the table contain headers you want to keep in the csv (and are usable as such)?

Comment: Yes first row in this contains header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite ready a solution but I have no more time ATM.

The script outputs all fields enclosed in double quotes and delimited with commas per row and stores in a variable $RawCSV which then is passed to `ConvertFrom-Csv`
I had trouble with a cr/lf and char 7 in the cell values which I replace with nothing

```
## Q:\Test\2018\07\17\SO_51385204.ps1

$CsvName = '.\Test.csv'
$filename = (Get-Item ".\Test-text.docx").FullName
$tableNum = 4
$delimiter = ','

$objWord = New-Object -Com Word.Application
$objWord.Visible = $true # $false

$objDocument = $objWord.Documents.Open($filename)

$LETable = $objDocument.Tables.Item($tableNum)
$LETableCols = $LETable.Columns.Count
$LETableRows = $LETable.Rows.Count

Write-Output "Starting to write... "
# "Table rows:{0} cols:{1}" -f $LETableRows,$LETableCols

$RawCSV = for($r=1; $r -le $LETableRows; $r++) {
    $content= @()
    for($c=1; $c -le $LETableCols; $c++) {
        #Write-Host ("R:{0},C:{1}" -f $r,$c)
        $content += ("`"{0}`"" -f $LETable.Cell($r,$c).Range.Text -replace "(`r|`n|`t)|$([char]7)?")
    }
    $Content -join $delimiter
}
$Csv = $RawCSV | ConvertFrom-Csv

$objDocument.Close()
$objWord.Quit()
# Stop Winword Process
$rc = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objWord)

$Csv
$Csv | Export-Csv $CsvName -NoTypeInformation
```